# Brownie ParserError openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol when deploying on default local ganache

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not found.
```

While I'm deploying with brownie on default local ganache-cli.

**Command:**

```
$ brownie compile
```

**gets:**

```
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.11
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not found.
```

**Token file head:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract InvestToken is ERC20 {
```

brownie-config.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin = OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2'
```

**command:**

```
$brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2
```

**gets:**

```
FileExistsError("Package is aleady installed")
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake in the brownie-config.yaml file:

I wrote:

```
remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin = OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2'
```

and it is

```
remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2'
```

sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Base on your error I think is relate with brownie-config.yaml
when new line don't use tab, use space

my issue with brownie-config.yaml

```
dependencies: 
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
compiler: 
  solc: 
    ramappings: 
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0'
dotenv: .env
wallets: 
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

when I fixed form tab to space

```
dependencies:
 - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
compiler:
 solc:
  remappings:
    - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

also u can check [ref](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/erc20-brownie-py/blob/main/brownie-config.yaml) from Patrick: